# on ready state change multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm using this method to set a function for when the page is loaded.

It works fine but I want to actually call various set of functions on different pages. The problem is each time I include this code overwrites the previous one so only one function is launched on page load.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'interactive') {

  } else if (state == 'complete') {
    myFunc();
  }

}
```

So how would I add functions instead of creating a new one for onreadystatechange each time?

Comment: Use `addEventListener`.

Comment: And why, and for what, are you using `onreadystatechange`? Sounds like you should be using [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) instead ?

Comment: Surely the same thing will happen with DOMContentLoaded

Comment: If you want different code to run on different pages, only link to the code you want to run on the page on which you want it to run...

Comment: Actually DOMContentLoaded combine with addEventListener does work fine thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need `document.addEventListener()`. This approach allows you to assign multiple functions to the same event.

Combination of info and example code found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState):

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(evt) {
  switch (evt.target.readyState) {
    case "loading":
      // The document is still loading.
      break;
    case "interactive":
      // The document has finished loading. We can now access the DOM elements.
      break;
    case "complete":
      // The document and all sub-resources have finished loading.
      myFunc();
      break;
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: It arrives multiple times for me. Weird.

Comment: @CsabaToth This listener gets called multiple times with different readyState string values - thus, the switch/case. If it's getting called multiple times with the same readyState value, I'm guessing multiple listeners got assigned to the same event?